# Other ways of saying "...began eating?"

Tags: phrases

I could only think of "*started on the food*," though I'm not very sure about it (I think I have to add *got* to it?).

Other suggestions? (this is for a short story I'm writing).

Comment: "commenced systematic routine of dietary nourishment"? As in: "Have you commenced systematic routine of dietary nourishment yet?" "Yes, I finished my systematic routine of dietary nourishment before I left the house"

Comment: If you could tell us how you're trying to use it, we could offer better suggestions on what phrase would be best.

Comment: @Zibbobz OK, done.

Comment: There's a million ways: `The meal began with a scrumptious salad enjoyed by all`

Comment: "Picked up a chicken wing...", "Spread a napkin on his lap and picked up his fork...", "Cracked open the bones of the zebra carcass with his powerful jaws before supping on the marrow..."

Comment: The fact that the comment above says "There's a million ways" shows that this question is primarily opinion-based. Also, since it's to do with writing, it might be better on [writers.se].

Comment: "initiated the stuffing of their pie-holes" is another good way to say it.  >_>

Comment: Writing advice is off topic at [elu.se]. Please read the [help] for more information on the types of questions and answers collected here. For writing advice try over at [writers.se]; check their help file first though.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

*tucked in* could work, informally, but is rather British - possibly also Australian.

Comment: is *..started ont he food* OK, also?

Comment: *started on the food* works, (no need for *got*).

Comment: And rather British, say what?

Comment: @bib absolutely, old chap - I'll edit, in fact.

Answer (score 3):

You could say *chowed down* or *dug in*, both also informal.

If it is an imperative, saying *Eat up* also suggests starting.

As noted in a comment, these are US usages.

Comment: Both of these are rather American sounding, by the way.

Answer (score 2):

"Dig in" is a common US slang for "begin to eat", though it is just as informal as the UK term that means the same thing - "tuck in".

"Start on the food" would be okay, though it sounds a bit awkward.